# How To Avoid Triggering A Click Event

Tags: jquery, jeditable

I have a toggle panel script in jQuery whereby my content expands and collapses when I click the h2 element.

Problem is I have input fields in that h2 element, which come about when I try to edit something using jEditable. I would like to find a way so that when I click on that input field, I don't get a click event.

My guess is somehow to use the `:not` selector method but I've tried a bunch of iterations to no avail.

CODE

```
    //toggle panel content
    $(".panelcollapsed h2").click(function(){
        $(this).siblings(".panelcontent").slideToggle(100, 'easeInQuad');
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could test to see if the event originated on an `input` element, and ignore it if it did:

```
$(".panelcollapsed h2").click(function(e){
    if (e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'input') {
        return;
    }

    $(this).siblings(".panelcontent").slideToggle(100, 'easeInQuad');
});
```

This checks the `tagName` of [`e.target`](http://api.jquery.com/event.target), the element where the event originated, to see if it is the same as `input`. If so, `return` exits the event handler.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check `event.target`:

```
//toggle panel content
$(".panelcollapsed h2").click(function(e){
    if ($(e.target).is('h2'))
       $(this).siblings(".panelcontent").slideToggle(100, 'easeInQuad');
});
```

Comment: Yes, that's the other way, but it is much slower. It also would fail on, for instance, `<h2><span>foo</span></h2>`.

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure what your DOM looks like, so just shooting in the dark here. Perhaps, using `e.stopPropagation()` in the input's click function could do the trick?

Answer (score 0):

on your input inside the h2 tag, you can add an event.stopPropagation() on his onclick.

```
$('#inputInsideH2').click(function(event){
   event.stopPropagation();
   $(this).focus();
};
```

the event.stopPropagation() will stop the propagation of the click event.